# Jenkins - MSBuild section is missing in system configuration

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

From MSBuild Plugin Page:

> To use this plugin, specify the location directory of MSBuild.exe on
>   Jenkin's configuration page.

Jenkins 2.7.2 LTS is installed on Windows as a service with recommended plugins on startup.

Then I installed MSBuild plugin v1.26
Restarted Jenkins, but still I cannot see any MSBuild section in 'Configure System' page.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've seen some of my plugin's settings going into "Global Tool Configuration". See the image:

[image: Jenkins settings]

Comment: even this new post is targeting to Configure System but yeah, I found it the page you shown. Thanks so much.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878203/Integrate-Jenkins-with-MSBuild-and-NuGet

Comment: I learned of it the hard way, even after re-installing different versions of the plugin...

Comment: That was my plan B (: